# Changing content in Embedded Resources file

Tags: c#, text, text-files

I want to change the content of a file loaded as a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) from an embedded resource.

The following code gets the file:

```
Stream theFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("_3LinksFourmTool.Resources.fourmlinks.txt");
```

I created a method that takes a string of text that is present in the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) provided. The string is rewritten to the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) with the new content.

```
public static void WriteNewTextToFile(string text, Stream theFile)
{

    string fileText = GetAllTextFromFile(theFile);
    ArrayList fileLIst = populateListFromText(fileText);

    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(theFile))
    {
        fileWriter.Write("");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLIst.Count; i++)
        {
            fileWriter.WriteLine(fileLIst[i].ToString());        
        }
    }
}
```

The above code throws the [System.ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Does this exception have anything to do with the text file being an `Embedded Resource`?

How can I modify this file without the [System.ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) being thrown?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is fileWriter.Write(""); supposed to be fileWriter.Write(text); ?

Comment: nope, i made this so the file will be empty befor i rewrite every thing agian.

Comment: Please post the code for how you are getting the `Stream` `theFile`

Comment: @user1556110 i added the code. is that what u mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources cannot be modified at runtime, in part because the executable is executing at the time, and no writes could be made to it. you can use an external binary editor to modify them, if all you have is the assembly, or you can recompile your project with the altered file. In most app platforms, in order to open a resource for write or execute, you must extract the file from the binary first, and then perform your ops on it. you can;t put it back however.

here are some links on how to manipluate resources at design/compile time:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd818wbk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

in this case, have you considered using Settings, instead of resources? They can be saved at runtime, so if you just need text value stuff, that should work well for you.

Comment: thanks for the info, but im not filimier with Settings. can u give me an example or mybee a usefel link u know?

Comment: this should help you: its a ..net 2 article, but Settings haven't really changed much since then. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx . Edit: Here is one specifically for VS 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx