# How to merge a text file and embed it in C# code build

Tags: c#, text

I create a class library and added a text file as one of the resource for the project.
I use it like this:

```
    string commandFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"data\vaCommands.txt");
```

When i release this dll i do not want this text file (data\vaCommands.txt) to be visible for users.
Is there a way to compile it to the code?
What is the best approach in these situations?

Comment: Yes... You have to change it’s _Build Action_ property to _Embedded Resource_. Your way of reading the file does not work anymore. Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

Add file to `Resources.resx`
Open up the `Resources.resx` file, use the dropdown box to add the file, set `Access Modifier` to `public`.
[image]

then you can get text if file like that:

```
string text = Properties.Resources.vaCommands;
```

Comment: I tried but it only added parts of the file - is there a limit to the # of rows for txt file? In addition I forgot to mention that i keep updating the textfile externally and i need these changes to be reflected in the build.

Comment: @dandan you can't update embedded files at runtime 
see this thread :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941957/changing-content-in-embedded-resources-file) .
if you need anther way , try to encrypt file without embedded it

Comment: for max `string` **size** see this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string)

Comment: @TENCO I do not want to update the file in runtime. I want to update it before but updating the file is done by excel. I export the text file before the build but i want the changes to be reflated in it

Comment: I don't know the limitation of size . but yes you can update file that will placed in your_project\Resources folder @dandan